Hashed email & phone submission to datalayer after form submission
I was trying to push to dataLayer hashed email and phone number (for later transfer to GTM and then to FB), using a code below. Unfortunately it doesn't work - email and phone are still coming unhashed. Could someone help me with that? Thanks in advance!
// Function to hash a string using SHA-256
async function hashString(str) {
    try {
        const msgUint8 = new TextEncoder().encode(str); // Encode string as UTF-8 Uint8Array
        const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", msgUint8); // Hash the message using SHA-256
        const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer)); // Convert buffer to byte array
        const hashHex = hashArray.map((b) => b.toString(16).padStart(2, "0")).join(""); // Convert bytes to hex string
        return hashHex;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error in hashString function:", error);
        return str; // Return the original string if hashing fails
    }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const form = document.querySelector(".elementor-form"); // Adjust this selector to match your form's class or ID

    if (form) {
        form.addEventListener("submit", async function (event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission

            const formData = new FormData(form);
            const formInputs = {};

            formData.forEach((value, key) => {
                formInputs[key] = value;
            });

            console.log("Original formInputs:", formInputs); // Debug: Log original form inputs

            // Hash the email if the field exists
            if (formInputs["email"]) {
                try {
                    const hashedEmail = await hashString(formInputs["email"]);
                    formInputs["email"] = hashedEmail; // Replace the plain email with hashed email
                    console.log("Hashed email:", hashedEmail); // Debug: Log hashed email
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error("Error hashing email:", error);
                }
            }

            // Hash the phone number if the field exists
            if (formInputs["phone"]) {
                try {
                    const hashedPhone = await hashString(formInputs["phone"]);
                    formInputs["phone"] = hashedPhone; // Replace the plain phone number with hashed phone number
                    console.log("Hashed phone:", hashedPhone); // Debug: Log hashed phone
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error("Error hashing phone:", error);
                }
            }

            // Convert formInputs object to a JSON string
            const formInputsString = JSON.stringify(formInputs);
            console.log("Final formInputsString:", formInputsString); // Debug: Log final string

            // Push to the data layer
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            window.dataLayer.push({
                event: "contest_submit",
                formId: form.id, // Or any other form data you want to capture
                formName: form.name, // Or any other form data you want to capture
                formInputs: formInputsString // Include the JSON string
            });

            // Optionally, you might want to manually submit the form or perform further actions
            // e.g., send data to a server or show a confirmation message
        });
    }
});

i was trying to debug in browser, but could not do so :(

When you say still coming unhashed.. where, in the fromData, formIput, dataLayer because to it seems to be working fine and the dataLayer has the relevant hashed data. It will be helpful to you if you can create a dempo replicating the problem you are facing..
